# Need table like widget

Tags: javascript

Can anybody suggest me an easy table like widget ( something like GridView in ASP.NET ) which I can easy fill with data from JSON file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Dojo [Data Grid](http://pastehtml.com/view/1duy1hy.html) ([Dojo documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/data/usingdatastores/simple.html))

Answer (score 1):

YUI [DataTable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/)